# Finding examples of field isomorphisms

Tags: field-theory

I am looking for an example of two fields that are isomorphic, infinite, and not equal.

I have found examples such as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \cong \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[3]{2}(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}) )$ where each of these fields is obtained by adding one of the roots of $x^3 - 2$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. However, I cannot seem to find an example of isomorphic fields that are not obtained in this way, that is, are not obtained by adding different roots of some irreducible polynomial.

Comment: But if you have that $\mathbb{Q}(a)\cong \mathbb{Q}(b)$ with $a$ going to $b$ then $a$ and $b$ must satisfy the same poly. And any isomorphism can be written this way.

Comment: On the other hand $\mathbb{Q}(e)\cong \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ but they are not equal.

Comment: So if a and b are algebraic over Q and Q(A) $\cong$ Q(b), they must satisfy the same polynomial? Is that obvious, is there any easy way for me to see that?

Comment: The isomorphism preserves addition and multiplication.

Comment: are we assuming a gets sent to b in the isomorphism?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Your second comment (about adjoining different transcendental elements ) should be an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Very generally, given any kind of structure, you can get an isomorphic structure that is not equal by just renaming the elements of your structure.

In your case, let $X$ be any infinite field with operations $+_X$ and $\cdot_X$, and let $Y$ be any set which has the same cardinality as $X$ but is not equal to $X$.  Let $f:Y\to X$ be some bijection.  Define operations of addition and multiplication on $Y$ by $a+_Yb=f^{-1}(f(a)+_Xf(b))$ and $a\cdot_Y b=f^{-1}(f(a)\cdot_X f(b))$.  These operations make $Y$ a field, and make $f:Y\to X$ an isomorphism of fields.  But $Y$ is not equal to $X$.